# How to insert data to database with subquery using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm going to insert into database id_user, date_registration and time_registration, but that not working. A problem involve id_user, but I don't know where. I hope someone help me.

```
public function insert_statistics()
{
    $login = $this->data['login'];
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $time = date('H:i:s');
     
    if(empty($this->validation->getErrors())) {
         $query = $this->database->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO statystics
                    (`id_user`, `date_registration`, `time_registration`) 
            VALUES((select id from users 
                    where login = :login
                    ),
                :date_registration, :time_registration)");

        $query->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $query->bindParam(':date_registration', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $query->bindParam(':time_registration', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
        $query->execute();
         
    }
 
}
```

Comment: _but that not working_ Is not really helpful. Please show us any error messages

Comment: The program shows no errors. This function simply does not insert data into the table

Answer (score 0):

for an insert select You should use this syntax

```
"INSERT INTO statystics (`id_user`, `date_registration`, `time_registration`) 
 select id,   :date_registration, :time_registration
 from users 
 where login = :login"
```

NB don't use

```
select id from users where login = :login, :date_registration, :time_registration    <---this i wrong
```

but use

```
 select id,   :date_registration, :time_registration
 from users 
 where login = :login
```

as is

```
if(empty($this->validation->getErrors())) {
     $query = $this->database->connect()->prepare(
           "INSERT INTO statystics (`id_user`, `date_registration`, `time_registration`) 
            select id,   :date_registration, :time_registration
            from users 
         where login = :login");

    $query->bindParam(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $query->bindParam(':date_registration', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
    $query->bindParam(':time_registration', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: I don't understand this query

Comment: answer  updated ..  removing wrong 'elec'  ..let me know

Comment: That not working now.

Comment: show me the exact  error message

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '2021-02-12', '18:41:05'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\insert.php:78 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\insert.php(78): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\index.php(101): Insert->insert_statistics() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\messbox\klasy\insert.php on line 78

Comment: show me the exact code you are really using  ..

Comment: `$query = $this->database->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO statystics(`id_user`, `date_registration`, `time_registration`) select id from users where login = :login, :date_registration, :time_registration");
  $query->bindParam(':login',$field, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
  $query->bindParam(':date_registration', $field20, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
  $query->bindParam(':time_registration', $field100, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
  $query->execute();`

Comment: yiu are not using my  code you are using a wrong code ..  try use my code as is .. just change you sql string with mine

Comment: A delete my code above and I add your code `INSERT INTO statystics (`id_user`, `date_registration`, `time_registration`) select id, from users  where login = :login :date_registration, :time_registration`.

Comment: ..  you don't have to add the param after the where  ..is worng  .. use my code  as is answer clearly updated

Comment: But should I remove bindParam and execute ?

Comment: answer  update with full code  --